# Read outside container Docker

Tags: docker

How can I read a file in outside of docker container?

For example: I have a file asd.txt in /etc/share/example/asd.txt in my server machine and I need to access this into my docker container.

It's possible?

Comment: *It's possible?* Yes. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: If your key goal is to access host-system system-level configuration, though, running in a container system that intentionally makes this difficult probably isn’t what you’re after.  Run it directly on the host.

Comment: @DavidMaze I did run it on the host. It's working!

Answer (score 1):

Mount the path as a volumne and you can access it in your container:

```
docker run -v /etc/share/example/:<destination>:ro ...
```

For more informations see: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to investigate [mounting a volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) into your container.